# How to check if previous week's data matches current week's data in R

Tags: r, character

I have a dataframe in R that contains a column with a specific character string and the week that data was obtained. I need to create a new column that returns a 0 or a 1 if the character string from the current week matches the character string from the previous week.

For example, trying to create the column "Match" below.

Thank you for your help!

```
Week     Data      Match
 1       Red         0
 2       Blue        0
 3       Blue        1
 4       Yellow      0
 5       Green       0
 6       Blue        0
 7       Blue        1
 8       Blue        1
 9       Green       0
 10      Yellow      0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a slightly modified data set that includes non-consecutive *Weeks*, using `diff` to measure the distance and `lag` to test the matches.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Match = (if_else(c(0, diff(Week)) == 1, Data == lag(Data), FALSE))*1)
   Week   Data Match
1     1    Red     0
2     2   Blue     0
3     3   Blue     1
4     4 Yellow     0
5     6  Green     0
6     7   Blue     0
7     8   Blue     1
8    10   Blue     0
9    11  Green     0
10   12 Yellow     0
```

##### mod. data

```
df <- structure(list(Week = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12), Data = c("Red", 
"Blue", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Green", 
"Yellow")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lag()` function from the `dplyr` package. You can then replace the first value with 0 using another `ifelse` function.

```
test <- data.frame(Week = 1:5, Data = c("Red", "Blue", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green"))

library(tidyverse)

test %>% 
  mutate(Match = ifelse(Data == lag(Data, default = "NA"), 1, 0))

 Week   Data Match
1    1    Red     0
2    2   Blue     0
3    3   Blue     1
4    4 Yellow     0
5    5  Green     0
```

Edit based on @peter861222 suggestion for default parameter in lag function.

Comment: This can be simplify: ```test %>% 
  mutate(Match = ifelse(Data == lag(Data,default = "NA"), 1, 0))``` or even ```test %>% 
  mutate(Match=+(Data==lag(Data,default = "NA")))```